# Serverless Deployment Failure: "service" property is not accessible

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless, bitbucket-pipelines

Any ideas why this Serverless Framework deployment is failing? It uses a bitbucket pipeline, which has a step to deploy to AWS.

On the actual deployment, though, it seems to run into issues accessing the `service` property in the serverless.yml file?

- The AWS certificate is valid

`Environment`

```
linux, node 12.22.12, framework 3.28.1, plugin 6.2.3, SDK 4.3.2
```

`Script Step`

```
- step:
        trigger: manual
        name: Dev Deployment
        deployment: dev
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - sls deploy --stage dev --client myclient --domain thewebsite.com --account-map '{"account":"1"}' --cert-arn 'arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:[ID]:certificate/[UUID]'
```

`Serverless.yml`

```
variablesResolutionMode: 20210326
service: ${self:provider.client}-reactions
stackName: ${self:provider.client}-reactions
description: "The system"

plugins:
  - serverless-domain-manager

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  client: ${opt:client}
  stage: ${opt:stage}
  domain: ${opt:domain}
  cert-arn: ${opt:cert-arn}
  account-map: ${opt:account-map}
  region: ${opt:region,'us-east-1'}
  logRetentionInDays: 14 # Set the default RetentionInDays for a CloudWatch LogGroup
  deploymentBucket: ${opt:bucket,'serverless.com'}
```

Error

```
Cannot resolve serverless.yml: "service" property is not accessible (configured behind variables which cannot be resolved at this stage)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Parameterized org, app, service, stage, and region usage* has been [deprecated](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations/#new-variables-resolver)

You'll need to define `service` using plaintext.

Comment: Even with `variablesResolutionMode: 20210326`? I think its really restricting if you have multiple AWS accounts sharing an implementation

Comment: @LJones yes, setting that value opts you into using the new resolver that specifies those deprecations.